# Question about $\mathbb{P^1}$ - without loss of generality doubt

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I want to show that:

> Given three distinct points $P_1,P_2,P_3 \in \mathbb{P}^1$ and three distinct points $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3 \in \mathbb{P}^1$, there is a unique isomorphism $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $f(P_i)=Q_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,3\}$.

My question is:

> Why do we can suppose without loss of generality that $P_1=0, P_2=1$ and $P_3=\infty$?

If someone can carefully explain this I'd be grateful.

By the way, I think I can solve the rest of the problem, no need to answer the whole problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we are guaranteed to have such an isomorphism $\phi_Q$, given any three $Q_i$; that is, $\phi_Q$ maps the triple $(0,1, \infty)$ to $(Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)$.

Then we would have such a $\phi_R$, which maps $(0, 1, \infty)$ to $(R_1, R_2, R_3)$, for any $R_i$'s we want.

What would happen to $(Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)$, using the isomorphism $\phi_R \circ \phi_Q^{-1}$?

Comment: $\phi_R \circ \phi_Q^{-1}(Q_i)=R_i$; What means this?

Comment: We have $Q_i=f_Q \circ f_R^{-1}(R_i)$, so we can conclude? It is obvious that we can conclude, but I don't know how to write this...

Comment: @Leafar Then, using this composition, you could map any triple $(Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)$ to any other triple, $(R_1, R_2, R_3)$; there would be no loss of generality working with $(0, 1, \infty)$, as it would immediately imply the fully general theorem.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot